# GCP Bucket gcfuse and Kubernetes Engine rights

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I mounted a GCP Bucket into my Kubernetes engine application, this part worked as I can see my bucket folders in my application. But I'm trying to interact with those files and the application does not have the writting right on these.

How can I change this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like support issue ask GCP support about it:
https://support.google.com/cloud

Comment: Solved : this was an issue with the scope of my node pols, I just added the "storage-full" permission during the creation and it worked !